# Using 'LIKE' in SQL Statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql

I seem to be able to do a simple query that uses the equal sign, but am unable to find any results when I use the 'LIKE' function. Am I missing something here?

```
SELECT ISARPapers.*, AuthorList.FirstName, AuthorList.LastName 
FROM AuthorList INNER JOIN (ISARPapers INNER JOIN PaperAuthor 
       ON ISARPapers.PaperID = PaperAuthor.PaperID) 
       ON AuthorList.AuthorID = PaperAuthor.AuthorID 
WHERE ISARPapers.PaperTitle LIKE '%Mianzi%'
```

Comment: maybe no data like that?

Comment: I confirmed that there is such a word in the title.

Comment: The way you are using the LIKE statement is correct.  Perhaps the problem is in your JOINS or table data.

Comment: What is the collation?

Comment: Which DBMS ? Some databases don't use %_ as wildcard characters. Also try `SELECT * FROM ISARPapers.PaperTitle LIKE '%Mianzi%'`, if this will work, then the problem will be not with LIKE, but with join.

Comment: I'm using Access as the DBMS

Comment: In Access, use the asterisk character instead of the percent character: `'*Mianzi*'`

Answer (score 1):

be carrefuly with capital letters

```
... WHERE ISARPapers.PaperTitle LIKE '%Mianzi%'
```

maybe *Mianzi* does not exists but *mianzi* does.
if you do not care about capitals, try:

```
... WHERE lower(ISARPapers.PaperTitle) LIKE '%mianzi%'
```